# Cacti - Unable to find certain search query results (Search Returned no Rows.)

Tags: php, debian, apache2, snmp, cacti

Posting question here since no response on cacti forums.

We are using older version of cacti Version 0.8.8b for graphing and and monitoring our network.  Most of features and graphs are working fine despite the old version. But recently we got an issue that unable to create graph for certain interfaces due to search query not showing any data.

I tried to create graph using  New Graphs -> host -> snmp interface statistics -> search the if-index. but this search return with [b]Search Returned no Rows[/b] error. But most if-index values within the same device I can search and create graph without any issue.

Then I tried to search the same if-index data from the snmpwalk tool.

```
snmpwalk -c ourcomm -v2C 192.168.1.11 | grep xxxxxxx
```

and I can see the if-index value returned as a grep result after some time ( like after 1min)

Then I try to do the [b]Reload associated query [/b] option from the cacti web ui. it took around 1 min and complete the refresh. but did not fix the issues. I did the reload few times without any luck.  While I doing the reload I tail the cacti log file and there were many timeout warnings.

```
01/23/2022 06:25:02 AM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] WARNING: SNMP Get Timeout for Host:'192.168.1.11', and OID:'.x.x.x.x.x.xx.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x
01/23/2022 06:25:02 AM - CMDPHP: Poller[0] Host[3] DS[475] WARNING: Result from SNMP not valid.  Partial Result: U
```

I tried to configure few of PHP parameters and snmp timeouts as below

From php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
```

cacti -> settings -> General ->

```
SNMP Timeout = 500
```

cacti -> settings -> Poller ->

```
Script and Script Server Timeout Value = 60
The Maximum SNMP OID's Per SNMP Get Request = 25
```

But even after all of this changes, I still cannot see the if-index on search query window. Anyone have idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like IfTable/IfXTable walk is timing out. Use snmpwalk to see (don't use grep, just walk the IfTable/IfXtable tree.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but snmpwalk -c ourcomm -v2C 192.168.1.11 ifTable giving me output ifTable: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> ifTable)

Comment: Update. I managed to fix this by increase per device snmpwalk timeout and fully reload associated data query